# Jquery DataTable(table tool) button,how to fire the click event with the button on another toolbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, datatable, tabletools

I am using CSV button in data table using table tools plugin.with this code only-

```
var table=$('#srvc_data_table').dataTable( {
        "data": dataSet,
        "columns": table_headings,
        "dom": 'T<"clear"><"H"lfr>t<"F"ip>',
        "tableTools": {     
        "sSwfPath": "../swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",        
        },
        });
```

button is declared in tableTools.js(tabletools plug-in file) as below ->

```
TableTools.BUTTONS = {
    "csv": $.extend( {}, TableTools.buttonBase, {
        "sAction": "flash_save",
        "sButtonClass": "DTTT_button_csv",
        "sButtonText": "CSV",
        "sFieldBoundary": '"',
        "sFieldSeperator": ",",
        "fnClick": function( nButton, oConfig, flash ) {
            this.fnSetText( flash, this.fnGetTableData(oConfig) );
        }
    } ),
```

CSV button is getting added on data table.
But I dont want to place this button on table itself.I want this button on another toolbar.
I want to detach the button from table or fire its click event from another button on different toolbar.Is it possible to fire fnClick event from another button.

Comment: need to add what you have doe yet. read well http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Sujith Karivelil - as per your suggestion I have edited my question.Please see if you understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the direct initialization [method](http://www.datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/initialisation). You can then utilize the `fnContainer()` API method to insert your csv button into your document.

ie `$( tableTools.fnContainer() ).insertAfter('div.info')`